# Proxy balancer and Apache Virtual Host multiple domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching, mod-rewrite, proxy

We have the following configuration, one apache HTTP server which proxies AJP requests to an application on another as in the Proxy balancer configuration below.

The problem we have is the application only understands one HOST http header, i.e exampledomain.com, but we require www.exampledomain.com to be rewritten to exampledomain.com however still show the www.exampledomain.com address.

We also have HTTP proxies in between the browser and hitting the Apache server, and do not want this content to be cached!

The following is our configuration:

```
<Proxy balancer://ajp-cluster>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
BalancerMember ajp://10.10.10.11:8009
</Proxy>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName exampledomain.com
ServerAlias exampledomain.com *.exampledomain.com
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.exampledomain.com
   RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://exampledomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,E=nocache:1]
   ## Set the response header if the "nocache" environment variable is set
   ## in the RewriteRule above.
   Header always set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" env=nocache
   ## Set Expires too ...
   Header always set Expires "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" env=nocache
   ProxyPass / balancer://ajp-cluster/
   ProxyPassReverse / balancer://ajp-cluster/
   </VirtualHost>
```